# how to see the values in the computer

Tags: usb

I am new in this topic, and maybe, it´s a stupid question but I cannot solve it.

I am using Pi in The Sky, I connect it to my computer by USB. And I know it is working because after some minutes the red led stops, and I see the green one. How can I see the value of the coordenates in my computer??

Thank you

Comment: Congratiulation! You have successfully powered your Pi. What Model is it? What else did you wire up except the power supply?

Comment: Thanks! I have bought the Pi In The Sky Zero Kit (https://store.uputronics.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=62&product_id=96) I have used the software in Github, but I have no more connected. I suppose that the radiometrix board and the temperature sensor are included. Am I correct?

Comment: Without knowing the system that has been delivered (I assume it was preinstalled on the microSD) I'd suggest you buy a USB-Ethernet adaptor (http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Ethernet_adapters) or a WiFi dongle (http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) (optionally setup WiFi (https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/)) and enable SSH (https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/).